# tf_tree does not show anything

Tags: ros-melodic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf_tree was work normally, but suddenly it does not show anything [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CrzljB_nRa55oQQ8o4i1WfZK593oZID6/view?usp=sharing).

```
rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360218/tf_tree-does-not-show-anything/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-08-25**:
thanks a lot, you saved me.
the following command solved the problem

```
rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree --clear-config
```

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-08-25**:
Awesome! In that case, I converted my comment to an answer so that this question will show up as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems likely to be a problem with `rqt_tf_tree` specifically and not necessarily anything wrong with the `/tf` data available. Maybe try with `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree --clear-config`? Alternatively try with `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree -b pyqt` or `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree -b pyside`. You could also run `rqt` alone and add the `TF Tree` plugin (it's under the `Visualization` section).

As a sanity check you could use `rosrun tf view_frames` to generate a PDF of the `/tf` tree to make sure there isn't anything wrong with the underlying data.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1